# inline asm unknown

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, inline-assembly, att

```
static inline void *__memset(void *s, char c, size_t n) {
int d0, d1;
asm volatile (
    "rep; stosb;"
    : "=&c" (d0), "=&D" (d1)
    : "0" (n), "a" (c), "1" (s)
    : "memory");
return s;
}
```

What are "d0" and "d1" used for? Could you please explain all the code completely?Thank you!

Comment: Weird.  I can't even see how 'c' gets into AL for the rep stosb, never mind the funny locals.  Only UNIX developers who are used to using a 3-page bash script to copy one file to another could survive such syntax, (well, OK, maybe COBOL programmers as well:).

Comment: http://www.ibiblio.org/gferg/ldp/GCC-Inline-Assembly-HOWTO.html describes the GCC Inline Assembler syntax.

Comment: It's horrible. It's like obfuscated assembler, as if assembler isn't obfuscated enough as it is, ('rep stosb' - perfectly clear)..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*What are "d0" and "d1" used for?*

In effect, it says that the final values of `%ecx`, `%edi` (assuming 32-bit) are stored in `d0`, `d1` respectively. This serves a couple of purposes:

It lets the compiler know that, as outputs, these registers are effectively clobbered. By assigning them to temporary variables, an optimizing compiler also knows that there is no need to actually perform the 'store' operation.

The "=&" specifies these as *early-clobber* operands. They may be written to before all the inputs are consumed. So if the compiler is free to choose an input register, it shouldn't alias these two.

This isn't technically necessary for `%ecx`, since it's *explicitly* named as an input: `"0" (n)` - the 'rep' count in this case. I'm not sure it's necessary for `%edi` either, since it can't be updated before the input `"1" (s)` is consumed, and the instruction executed. And again, as it's *explicitly* named as an input, the compiler isn't free to choose another register. In short, "=&" doesn't hurt here, but it doesn't do anything.

As `"a" (c)` specifies an *input-only* register `%eax` set to `(c)`, the compiler may assume that `%eax` still holds this value after the 'asm' - which is indeed the case with `"rep; stosb;"`.

`"memory"` specifies that memory can be modified in a way unknown to the compiler - which is true in this case, it's setting `(n)` bytes starting at `(r)` to the value `(c)` - assuming the direction flag is cleared, which it should be. This does have the effect of forcing a reload of values, as the compiler can't assume that registers reflect the memory values they're supposed to anymore. It doesn't hurt, and it may be necessary to make it safe for a general case `memset`, but it's often overkill.

**Edit:** Input operands may not overlap clobber operands. It doesn't make sense to specify something as *input-only* **and** *clobbered*. I don't think the compiler allows this, and it wouldn't be wise to use an ambiguous specification even if it did. From the manual:

> You may not write a clobber description in a way that overlaps with an input or output operand. For example, you may not have an operand describing a register class with one member if you mention that register in the clobber list.

---

Reviewing some old answers, I thought I would add a link to the excellent [**Lockless**](https://locklessinc.com/articles/gcc_asm/) GCC inline ASM tutorial. The article builds on prior sections, unlike the gcc manual which is best described as a 'reference', and not really suited to any sort of structured learning.

Comment: I now have a thought that the output section is to tell the compiler not to use %ecx and %edi except for output so they can keep correct. Is that true?

Comment: @akirast, yes, although the output is never *really* stored. If the compiler wants to use %ecx, %edi again, it knows that it will have to reload them.

Comment: @akirast, I should clarify: I wouldn't *expect* them to be stored. If optimizations are off, they might be. Probably are, if d0 and d1 can be inspected with debugging.

Comment: Thank you! I think I need to make an effort to understand what happen exactly.

Answer (score 3):

You need to understand gcc extended inline asm format:

- The first part is the actual assembly. In this case there are only 2 instructions
- The second part specifies output constraints and the third part specifies input constraints. The fourth part specifies the assembly will clobber the memory

#### Output

- `"=&c"` associates d0 with the ecx register and marks it for write-only. `&` means it can be modified before the end of the code
- `"=&D"` means the same thing, for the edi register

#### Input

- `"0" (n)` associates n with the first mentioned register. In your case, with ecx
- `"a" (c)` associates c with eax
- `"1" (s)` associates s with edi

#### Assembly

So there you have it. Repeat this ecx times (n times): store eax (c) into edi (s) then increment it.

---

*So then, why the unused `d0` and `d1`* ? I'm not sure. I too think they are useless in this case and the whole output section could be left empty BUT I don't think it's possible to specify "writable" and "**early**-clobbered" in the input constraints. So I think `d0` and `d1` are there to make `&` possible.

I would try writing it like this:

```
asm volatile (
    "rep\n"
    "stosb\n"
    :
    : "c" (n), "a" (c), "D" (s)
    : "%ecx", "%edi", "memory"
);
```

Comment: Nope, you can't declare a clobber on a register you're using as an input operand.  That's why the code uses dummy output operands instead of clobbers.  (Since it's inside a wrapper function, I would have just used `"+c"`(c) and `"+D"(s)` constraints that modify the C variables you give them.)

Comment: You don't need early-clobber when all the operands have fixed registers; there's nothing left for the compiler to choose like there would be with `"+r"` and `"r"`, where a compiler could go wrong if it knows that `a == n` and put them in the same register.